# In LiteSpeed, where is $VH_ROOT defined?

Tags: virtualhost, litespeed

After installing LiteSpeed, the first task when experimenting is often setting up a vhost.

When we look around dashboard at various settings we come across some variables. One of which is $VH_ROOT.

How can the value of $VH_ROOT be discovered?

Also, and more specifically, can the value of $VH_ROOT be discovered from the terminal? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root@test:~# cat /usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd_config.conf | grep vhRoot
    vhRoot                   Example/
  vhRoot                  /home/$VH_NAME
```

it's in the main conf file , the path is defined when you create the vhost in it

[image]

but be aware , this variable can only be used within vhost configuration , because in server configuration , there is no "$vh_root" defined yet in that context.